# How to find the specific attribute of a tag inside a script using Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, file

I've been looking here in stackoverflow how can I search for a String part inside big texts. But I haven't managed to find how to get an specific value of an attribute inside a Script using Java. The goal is read a file (script) line by line, and extract the value of an attribute "src".

For instance, the file has many lines containing this structure:

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/" src="js/require.min.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/" src="js/require.min.js"></script>
```

So, using Java I read the file this way using `BufferedReader` class, I want to get for each line the value of "src", for example, for the first line, I want to get: `js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js`, for the second line, I want to get `js/require.min.js` and so on, I saw some suggestions like using regex, but I don't know if it is the most effective in this cases:

```
public Helper(String scriptPath) {
        File scriptFile = null;
        try {
            scriptFile = new File(scriptPath);
            String relativePath = scriptFile.getParent();
            System.out.println(relativePath);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(scriptFile));
            String readLine;

            while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // How to match the src?
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please, if somebody could help me I will really appretiate it or if someone knows that there's already an answer for this, please let me know in order to close this, but at the time I've been searching, I haven't found this kind of problem yet.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Check out regular expressions and groups.

Comment: Are the script tags found inside of HTML or XML?  Either way, my suggestion is to use an HTML parser or an XML parser, respectively.

Comment: As Gilbert mentioned, you should use a parser for handle XML/HTML related tags.

Comment: the document will not contain necessarily tags for xml or html it can just contains the tag <script>, the file will contain the ".php" extension as well.

Comment: If it's a php file, you could miss some scripts unless you execute the file and capture the HTML output.  Then you could use an HTML parser to parse the HTML output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file looks like html I would consider using an Html Parser.
http://jsoup.org/ is very easy to use with css like selectors

Comment: actually, the file has ".php" extension. Does the Html Parser works with php files as well?

Comment: From what I know jsoup does not care about file extension

Comment: Thanks, I'm not allowed to use external jars or apis, but I will mark your answer as correct since it is the best option. Thanks.